# Padding floating div without moving other divs

Tags: html, css

Im trying to left-pad the "back" div by 30px but without nudging the "head" div from center. Cant seem to get it right. http://jsfiddle.net/bZeD9/

```
<div class='header top'>
    <div class="back">&lt;</div>
    <div class="head">HEADER HERE</div>
</div>

.header {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #4A4A4A;
    text-align: center;
    color: #F1F1F1;
    line-height: 45px;
    padding-top: 3px;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 100;
}

.back {
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `position:absolute`

```
.back {
    position:absolute;
    left:30px; 
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/q9aVK/)**

Comment: Legend! Thank you. I knew it would be something simple like that

Comment: @MitchellWeiss u r wlcm. Don't forget to add position:relative to parent div as I mentioned in the fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Set its positioning to relative and add left: 30px;

```
.back {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    left: 30px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jeffshaver/bZeD9/4/

Answer (score 0):

add

```
padding: 3px 30px 0;
```

to the css for the .header

Then you will have padding both on the right and the left side, so if you for some reason would put something in the right end of th header div, that would automaticly position 30px from the edge as well. I also added the 3px to the top since u already had that, so you can remove the `padding-top`.

I usually rather use this kind of solution rather than absolute positioning, that also works but is more static and i find it harder to maintain and change, that's my personal opinion.